The functions.stories.GetPeerStoriesRequest method does not return stories
The functions.stories.GetPeerStoriesRequest method does not return stories.
user_data = await client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(id=user))
user_stories = await client(functions.stories.GetPeerStoriesRequest(peer=user_data.users[0].username))

Or am I doing something wrong?
Python 3.9
Telethone 1.32.1

Figured it out myself. I had to do it like this:
user_data = await client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(id=user_id))
user_stories = await client(functions.stories.GetPeerStoriesRequest(
    peer = InputPeerUser(
        user_id = user_data.full_user.id,
        access_hash = user_data.users[0].access_hash
    )
))

